# Where are the brightness controls?

Tags: 18.04, brightness, system-settings

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently. I have been using Ubuntu for over 5 years I know that the brightness controls are inside the `Power` section in the settings but they are not there anymore. Searching for brightness still brings `Power` section in settings as the only result in `gnome-shell` but I can't seem to find it.

Can someone please tell me how I control my brightness in Ubuntu 18.04

Here is a screenshot of power tab in settings
[image: Power Settings no brightness control]

Comment: They do exist in the power settings.

Comment: I am not able to find them, wait I'll attach a screenshot

Comment: Well, that seems strange. Here is how the battery settings on PC look like : https://imgur.com/a/zY6nOeU. And I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: wow, that is completely different, I am using communiti theme, would that cause this problem?

Comment: are you also using communiti theme?

Comment: no, for now guys at canonical refrained from making it default, so it's probably some other issue

Comment: I tried the community theme right now, and the brightness settings still exist.  here is the link of a screenshot : 
https://imgur.com/a/TrQVCBn

Comment: Maybe some system dependency is there that we don't know of

Comment: The Ubuntu Manual Refers to Gnome. Do we need to install That? I would rather not install Gnome. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-brightness.html.en

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Gnome as a default Desktop environment, I didn't install any additional packages, it was working from the beginning without I add anything.

Comment: Ahhh, It says this at the beginning...."Depending on your hardware, you can change the brightness of your screen to save power or to make the screen more readable in bright light."

Comment: Aha, so it all depends on the hardware!

Comment: But it does not make sense, I was able to see the brightness controls in 17.10, I don't think that my 1 year old laptop is suddenly deprecated

Comment: Try this : install *xbacklight* and add it to startup applications

Comment: This at least gave me a way to control brightness, but still does not solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in a recent update. I am not sure which package was updated to fix this. So yeah I'm closing this question

Comment: Couldn't find it in 20.04. Where did you find the brightness settings?

Answer (score 7):

I took a moment searching the problem in the internet, one of the proposed solutions :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

Normally, after this, you will have the brightness controller. You can find it under **Settings**>**Power** menu or search it in Dash.

Comment: Nah, didn't work, but now I have a good application which allows me to change brightness for multiple monitors, huge help, but sadly not the solution I was looking for

Comment: So please mention it in an answer or a comment.

Comment: Mention what? I just want the brightness control bar to show up as it did in 17.10 for me

Comment: I mean mention the name of the application.

Comment: Wait I think I did not convey the message properly. I meant that the application you suggested `brightness-controller` is a good one. Helped me

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: works well! is there a way to associate the keyboard keys for brightness ? this is my last step to achieve a fully functional ubuntu on a apple hardware!

Comment: On a non apple computer brightness settings would be in the Fxx keys (F11, F12 for example). However I have no idea how to add that on apple hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using **`xlight`** in my Laptop:

> `sudo apt-get install xbacklight`

Set Brightness from 0 to 100:

> `xbacklight -set 50`

Dectrease or Incrase brighness:

> `xbacklight -dec 10`
>   `xbacklight -inc 10`

Comment: this had no effect on a ubuntu budgie  20.10 installation