# Xubuntu 18.04: make Fn brightness keys work with /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/

Tags: nvidia, xfce, brightness, backlight

I have an old laptop, oldtimer linux fellow, and updated it to xubuntu 18.04.

After some sleep/resume problems with the proprietary nvidia-340 driver, I decided to try the nouveau. Sleep/resume ok. But there is a new problem: the brightness.

Using the proprietary driver, with `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` in the `xorg.conf`, the <kbd>Fn-bright-up</kbd> and <kbd>Fn-bright-down</kbd> keys work out of the box.

With the nouveau driver they don't.

```
$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

returns `acpi_video0` and `nv_backlight`.

As expected nothing can be done using `acpi_video0`.

But, surprise! The `nv_backlight` is working:

```
$ echo 20 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
```

works!

But I don't know how to make my friend xfce knows that the <kbd>Fn-bright-up</kbd> and <kbd>Fn-bright-down</kbd> should talk with `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness` instead of `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`.

Thank you.

Comment: I modified the xfce4-power-manager_1.6.1 source code, changing xfpm-backlight-helper.c -> backlight_helper_get_best_backlight(), making it choose the raw backlight type instead of firmware or platform. It's a work for me only fix... Would be nice to have an option to change the preference order.

Answer (score 2):

The nouveau driver now (some time ago it didn't) creates the `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight` and it works. So passing `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the kernel disables the `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`. Without `acpi_video0`, the `backlight_helper_get_best_backlight()` will return the nv_backlight out of the box.

So, open /etc/default/grub, edit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="[...] acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Of particular interest to you is this question where `acpi_backlight=vendor` didn't work and a custom script was the solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045624/how-to-switch-between-options-in-sys-class-backlight-to-solve-brightness-prob

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody still has issues with Xubuntu 18.04 backlight keys, which enable Brightness popup however don't increase/decrease brightness bar, here is the way which helped me. It appears that brightness keys were simply disabled in XFCE4 power manager configuration:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/handle-brightness-keys
=> false
```

Therefore this fixed the situation:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/handle-brightness-keys --create -t bool -s true
```